# Play vs Grails performance difference

Tags: performance, grails, playframework

I'm trying to measure the performance of Play vs. Grails in a simple app. This app makes 100 queries to H2 in-memory db and returns a list of results. My measurement in JMeter when making 500 concurrent requests is:

Average response time:

- Play: 2 326 ms
- Grails: 214 124 ms

The Play app is running using "play stage" start script and the Grails app is packed into WAR and deployed to Tomcat. For Tomcat, I didn't change anything, and the same applies to the start script. Both of them are running in exactly the same environment. The apps are not optimized in any way because I want to test the default settings of these frameworks.

Do you have any ideas why the difference is so big?

Comment: I suspect because even a simple Grails app is far from that. There is a /huge/ amount of things going on even if you aren't using them. If you really want to do an apples to apples comparison you need to pull apart the Grails app and strip it down to the bare minimum. Turning off open session in view, http sessions, removing as much of the things that are present you aren't using specifically.

Comment: In Grails you have environments, the default is development, where the reloading mechanism is enabled, for a more accurate measure run `grails prod war` to create a war for production.

Comment: He said he's running a war in Tomcat - the default env for the war task is prod, so `grails prod war` is redundant. `grails test-app` is the other script that doesn't default to dev, it defaults to test.

Comment: @Joshua Moore do you mean Grails is slow for small apps, if I don't spent a lot of time learning how to tune it? Because for Play, I didn't do anything either, so I think it's apples to apples comparision.

Comment: @Sergio yep, my Grails app runs in prod war mode.

Comment: @LojzaIbg Tuning your app isn't what I am suggesting, all though that is a good idea if you want the best performance. What I am suggesting is understand what you are getting in a small app in Grails. Grails is a HUGE framework, built on Spring, and has a lot of features enabled/built in by default that you are likely not using and more than likely aren't enabled/available in your Play app. Simply putting together an app like you described and testing it for "performance" isn't really smart without knowing WHAT you are testing.

Comment: @LojzaIbg I'm not saying that Grails is slow. What I am saying is that your 'small app' isn't a small app at all. Grails is doing a WHOLE lot more than you think. So your comparison isn't valid.